# Fast buy & download list of songs on Google Play

Tags: automation, google-play-music

Is there an fast way to buy a bunch of songs from Google Play and download all of them as mp3 files? (A specific list of songs that is, not just any bunch of songs).

There are several steps that take too long:

1. Search each song, then look for it again in the album list. This one especially.
2. Buying the song (takes 7+ seconds for that window to do it's job, I get a load of emails, and Paypal blocked after too many transactions).
3. Downloading all of the songs. I can only find how to do it per album, but most songs are from different albums.

I'd love it if I could provide a list, check the matches are correct, then pay and download all of them at once. But I don't much care which way, any advice on either of the points is welcome.

I'm comfortable using command line tools (don't want to make them). I don't particularly care if it's officially allowed or not.

Comment: 3. I found that Google Music Manager can download all songs automatically. It's not a webapp, but it solves a webapp problem, so I hope it's okay.